# Symfony2 Export Annotation to XML

Tags: xml, symfony, routes, annotations

I have a Symfony2 project, the first one that I worked on, and I created it using annotations in the controllers for routing. Now this was obviously a big mistake. I would now like to move to xml as I am using it in other projects and it is working really well.

Is there a way that I can export all of the routing that already exists into xml to save me the effort of doing it manually?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you said that it was "obviously" a mistake to use annotations.  In fact, [Symfony best practices for Controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html) recommend using annotations:

However, if you want to use XML, you can get a quick reference of all of your routes with

```
php app/console router:debug
```

Regardless, it would likely be far more work to try to whip something up to automate this process than to just do it one time manually.

Comment: Thanks for that! So I'll just do that and manually create my xml files I guess. I thought I saw one of my collegues once actually use a tool to export straight to xml, but this'll be fine. I understand that annotations are "best practice", I just can't get into it. I much rather a separation of concerns and having php comments, something that shouldn't matter at all, break the system if there is something wrong.

Comment: You're welcome. That's one of the nice things about Symfony...it allows you to choose athe format that works best for you.  There is a tool at http://converter.rosstuck.com/ that will convert service definitions between yml and xml, but not annotations (and not for routes).  Maybe that's what you've seen before.  If there is another tool somewhere, I haven't seen it or can't find it.